# Symfony2: how to make a twig extension return an image

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to create my first twig estension

```
class UserExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
public function getFunctions() {
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('userThumbImg', array($this, 'getUserThumbImg')),
    );
}

public function getUserThumbImg()
{
    $thumbImage = Repository::getInstance('users')->getUserImg(4, true);
    return $thumbImage['image'];
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'user_extension';
}
}
```

The static repository class simply reads the file with fread. I'd like to call the image from twig in this way

```
<img class="user-photo" src="{{ userThumbImg() }}" alt="" />
```

but I get a binary string. what can I do to display the image in my template? I haven't tried to return a response because this is not a controller, should I have to do in that way?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always use a path to display an image. Save the image somewhere on the server and return that path. Or transform the image in a `data:` link and return that.

Comment: the image is not under document_root, I need a way to display it from outside the document_root

Comment: Yeah but even if it not on the document_root, what he said still true

Comment: I don't understand, can you please provide an example? thanks

Comment: @user3174311 Just read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) about `data:`. The simplest way is to convert your image to `base64`: `return 'data:image/'.$imageType.';base64,'.base64_encode($image);` and then insert this string in your `src` attribute.